# Install Pytorch GPU with pre-installed CUDA and cudnn

Tags: installation, pytorch, conda

As the title suggests, I have pre-installed CUDA and cudnn (my Tensorflow is using them).

The version of CUDA is **10.0** from `nvcc --version`.

The versiuon of cudnn is **7.4**.

I am trying to install pytorch in a conda environment using `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch`.

However, the installed pytorch does not detect my GPU successfully.

Does anyone know if there is a way to install GPU-version pytorch with a specific CUDA and cudnn version? I do not want to change CUDA and cudnn version because my Tensorflow is using them.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: If you type `nvidia-smi` in terminal, is the GPU recognized?

Comment: @JosephKonanYea, I have no issue with that. I can also detect my GPU using Tensorflow in my system.

Comment: It is possible the display driver version is too old compared to cuda version you are using. Showing the `nvidia-smi` output would help.

Comment: For a more detailed assessment, you could install numba and execute `numba -s`.

Comment: @JosephKonanI just checked using `nvidia-smi`, which shows I am using 430.50. It should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this myself finally. The issue is that I didn't reboot my system after installing pytorch. After rebooting, `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `True` as expected.